# How to retain enabled google apps and services on a copied worksheet with an attached script?

Tags: scripting, google-sheets-api, user-permissions

When a user makes a copy of our master sales quote sheet, they lose the permissions on the enabled google apps and services, and the driveApp, GmailApp, ContactsApp, SpreadsheetApp, fail in the scripts attached to the sheet.

Although the script has been running fine for a year, suddenly yesterday (Aug 23 2017) we found we needed to go to script resources, Advanced Google Services, and enable the associated services, in order to get the script to work.

OK, BUT: when the spreadsheet is copied, all those permissions are lost and have to be set again.

So, how do I make a global setting so that all copies of a script with apps enabled, get the same settings?

There is a [vague answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=enable%20apps%20and%20services%20for%20a%20google%20sheet%20script).

But it doesn't explain why our users had no problems with the script and copies made from it, until yesterday.

Comment: enable them again

Comment: @noogui.  Up until Aug 23, they were seemingly enabled permanently on all copies made from the original.  However, now the functions don't work unless the services are enabled on each and every copy.  As you say.  But that doesn't solve the copy issue.